# "Immediate out of range errors" when assigning 0.0 to a NEON register

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, arm, neon

If I understand it correctly, because ARM instructions are 32 bits long they can only hold so many bits of immediate value. What I'm trying to do is `vmov.f32 s0, #0.0`, and I get "`immediate out of range`" compiler error. Strange thing is that when I use an immediate value of, say `#0.5` or `#0.25` (all very neatly represented in binary), my code compiles. When I try to assign an immediate value of `#0.1`, I get the "`garbage after following instruction`" error, which makes sense if it's trying to represent those values with more bits that can fit into an ARM instruction. The `#0.0` case is the only one where I get "`immediate out of range`", so I'm thinking it's got to be a bug if there's no other explanation.

Does anyone know how to assign an immediate value of `#0.0` to a single word floating point register without having to convert it from somewhere else? If there's a good reason it shouldn't work in the first place, please let me know as well. I'm using GNU assembler with Android NDK build tool.

*Update*:
`vmov.f32 d0, #0.0` *does* work. It keeps making less and less sense.

*Update 2*:
This doesn't work either: `vmov.s32 s0, #0`

Comment: I haven't done any ARM assembly.  But just out of curiosity looked up the instruction to see what you're talking about.  So pardon my potentially naive question: isn't the designation of s32 a "Signed integer" type?  Are you sure you don't mean to use `vmov.f32 #0.0`?

Comment: @HostileFork You're right. It's a typo. Correcting the question.

Comment: You're missing a register for the first operand - or is that another typo ? Can you post the *actual* line of code that's causing the problem ?

Comment: Going further in the "just reading the documentation"...it says that VMOV in immediate mode should be used with `Qd or Dd`, which are Neon registers, while `s` registers are VFP.  Perhaps you're experiencing an issue with undefined behavior?  Also, note the [b] comments: "Any number that can be expressed as `+/- n * 2^(-r)`, where n and r are integers, 16 <= n <= 31, 0 <= r <= 7".  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204h/CIHGGEEB.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0.0` is not representable as a VFP/NEON floating-point immediate.  Representable floating-point immediates are between 1/8 and 31 in magnitude, which zero clearly isn't.

The corresponding bit pattern, however, *is* representable as an integer NEON immediate.  Your assembler is being helpful and generating this encoding for you instead of an (impossible) floating-point immediate; when you write `vmov.f32 d0, #0.0` it actually emits `vmov.s32 d0, #0`, which has the same effect as what you appear to be trying to do, but is actually a legal instruction.

`vmov.s32 s0, #0` doesn't make any sense; NEON does not provide any instructions that operate on `s` registers.

If you just want to zero a NEON register, however, the preferred idiom is usually `veor d0, d0`.  Is there a reason that you aren't using that?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `veor 0o, d0`, I just never thought of this solution. = ) Is there a particular reason `0.0` isn't representable in VFP/NEON innediate and is there perhaps a good in-depth read on this?

Comment: @Phonon: the reason is pretty simple: they only have 8 bits to use to represent immediates, and they don't want to waste them on values that you can produce by other means (either an integer immediate or `veor`).  As for reading, I would consult the ARM architecture reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign 0 to an s register, you can easily do by using the instruction:
vsub.f32 s0, s0, s0

Comment: Thid doesn't work when the previous value in s0 is not a normal number (e.g. +-Inf, NaN) in which case you will get a NaN in the register.

Answer (score 1):

For assigning "0" to a register(doesn't matter if it's general register or NEON vector) just do this:

```
"eor s0, s0, s0 \n\t"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this :
  vmov.u32 d0, #0

because 0x00000000 is interpreted as 0.0f as well.

FYI, there can't be any "true" zero in float. It's actually 1.0 * (2^-128)

or 1.0 * (2^-129), I don't remember exactly.

Comment: No.  `0x00000000` really is **exactly** 0.0.  (So is `0x80000000`).

Comment: @StephenCanon Read the IEEE754 spec sheet.

Comment: Jake, ordinarily I hate to appeal to authority, but I'll make an exception: I was a member of the IEEE-754 committee.  So believe me when I say that there really are exact zeros in IEEE-754 floating-point formats.  `0x00000000` is exactly 0.0.  `0x80000000` is exactly -0.0.

Comment: No, I'd rather trust offical papers than someone who used to be someone. Besides, I've been talking about "zero" all the time along, and you are trying to teach me "0.0" and "-0.0" for no reason. What's the point?

Comment: "0.0" and "-0.0" *are* "zero".  If you insist on references, see clause 3.3 "Within each format, the following floating-point data shall be represented: **Signed zero** ..." (emphasis mine).  If you prefer the previous (1985) revision of the standard, then you will want clause 3.2: "If `e=0` and `f=0` , then `v=(-1)^s 0` (**zero**)"

Comment: And why does it have to be declared so explicitly? It's a settlement to "interpret" this as a zero, because it actually isn't. I doubt someone would ever be capable of converting float to q256 fixed-point correctly without filtering out 0.0f and -0.0f which wouldn't be necessary if they were true zeros. We don't even need that many bits. A multiplication of two floats 0x0 and 0x7fffffff wouldn't result in 0x0 without this "special treatment".

Comment: Of course it's actually zero.  The standard defines it to be zero, just like the standard defines the interpretation of every other floating-point encoding.  It's worth noting that zero does not require special treatment; the value follows immediately from interpreting the encoding of zero according to the rules for denormal values.  Lastly, multiplying zero by `0x7fffffff` as floating-point values does *not* produce a zero result, as `0x7fffffff` is a NaN encoding -- the result is NaN.

Comment: And where does the single 1 go that you put in front of m? 1/n cannot be zero unless n is unlimited. And n isn't unlimited in float. Alone the fact that there are two zeros proves that there isn't actually any in float. I'm talking about math, and you about standard. And I didn't ask you. I'm talking about 34, and you are talking about ASC(34). Now I'm asking : is ASC(34) space?